# Problema no redirecionamento

Tags: node.js, apache

Estou criando uma aplicação em *node.js* usando express admin para gerenciar os dados. Rodou ótimo como localmente, mas quando coloco no servidor apache o redirecionamento para o login dá erro.

No caso, quando eu fosse para `http://localhost/sales/admin` deveria redirecionar para `http://localhost/sales/admin/login`, mas tá redirecionando para `http://localhost/login`, me retornando página não encontrada.

Segue o código do meu virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    Alias /sales /var/www/html
    <Location /sales>
        ProxyPass  http://localhost:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/
    </Location>

    Alias /sales/api /var/www/html
    <Location /sales/api>
        ProxyPass  http://localhost:6000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:6000/
    </Location>

    Alias /sales/admin /var/www/html
    <Location /sales/admin>
        ProxyPass  http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```